# angularJS 1.x how to get current element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have make many search in getting current element
in **jQuery :$(this)**
but in Angular J S 1.x i haven't found it  here what i have do **angular.element(this)** but it's not correct

here is my code i like to get current target element

```html
<html>
        <head>
            <style>
                .error{
                    color:red;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
    <body>
     <div ng-app="" ng-controller="eventController">
      <h2>AngularJS $event example</h2>
                    <input type="text" ng-change="handleChange($event)" ng-model="test" value="My Text"  class="testtt" >
     </div> 
        
     <script>
      function eventController($scope) {
          $scope.handleChange = function(event) {
                        var classname = event.target.currentTarget.className
                  console.log(classname);                        
              }
      }
      </script>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Share more details or plunkr url and **use directive to read elements**

Comment: It is correct, is might be that you have a problem with the context and `this` is not really referring to what you think you want to access. here is the documentation for angular.element https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: where you calling the angular.element?

Comment: Angular doesn't work the way jQuery works. In Angular, you don't select elements in the DOM in order to manipulate them. It works the other way round : you start from data, and then you build the DOM from it.

Comment: i have edit it by making more details

Comment: i like to get current target DOM element using angularJS

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into ng-class for what you are trying to do. If you really need direct access to an element, use a directive. The directives link function gets the element at initialisation time.

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution to my problem by using javascript 
**document.activeElement**